# pg_restore duplicate key and invalid command errors

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, database-backups, pg-restore

Postgres version :

```
PostgreSQL 9.2.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3), 64-bit
```

We transfer from one server to another (with better cpu an ram) our system using vm converter and when I try to backup database have an error :

```
pg_dump: reading schemas 
pg_dump: reading user-defined tables 
pg_dump: reading extensions 
pg_dump: reading user-defined functions 
pg_dump: reading user-defined types 
pg_dump: reading procedural languages 
pg_dump: reading user-defined aggregate functions 
pg_dump: reading user-defined operators 
pg_dump: reading user-defined operator classes 
pg_dump: reading user-defined operator families 
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search parsers 
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search templates 
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search dictionaries 
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search configurations 
pg_dump: reading user-defined foreign-data wrappers 
pg_dump: reading user-defined foreign servers 
pg_dump: reading default privileges 
pg_dump: reading user-defined collations 
pg_dump: reading user-defined conversions 
pg_dump: reading type casts 
pg_dump: reading table inheritance information 
pg_dump: reading rewrite rules 
pg_dump: finding extension members 
pg_dump: finding inheritance relationships 
pg_dump: reading column info for interesting tables 
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "account_account" 
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  missing chunk number 0 for toast value 3297740 in pg_toast_2619 
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: SELECT a.attnum, a.attname, a.atttypmod, a.attstattarget, a.attstorage, t.typstorage, a.attnotnull, a.atthasdef, a.attisdropped, a.attlen, a.attalign, a.attislocal, pg_catalog.format_type(t.oid,a.atttypmod) AS atttypname, array_to_string(a.attoptions, ', ') AS attoptions, CASE WHEN a.attcollation <> t.typcollation THEN a.attcollation ELSE 0 END AS attcollation, pg_catalog.array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT pg_catalog.quote_ident(option_name) || ' ' || pg_catalog.quote_literal(option_value) FROM pg_catalog.pg_options_to_table(attfdwoptions) ORDER BY option_name), E', 
    ') AS attfdwoptions FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid WHERE a.attrelid = '274619'::pg_catalog.oid AND a.attnum > 0::pg_catalog.int2 ORDER BY a.attrelid, a.attnum
```

I solve it using `reindexdb` ,after I try `pg_dump -U postgres my_db > /home/mydb.backup` and it was successfull. Then I try to restore database to ensure that backup is valid

```
psql -U postgres new_db < /home/mydb.backup
```

And have an errors :

```
ERROR : extra data after last expected column 
Context: COPY tbl1, line1: "1 2013-12-02 2013-12-02  9387.74  9775.46211485490864940000"   6180.9500000000   80262 ...." 
ERROR : column "id" of relation "tbl1" does not exists 
invalid command \N 
invalid command \N 
invalid command \N 
..... 
invalid command \N 
invalid command \. 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "87685" 
LINE 1: 87685 SO87690 1 170468 2015-05-30 2015 05 30 
        ^ 
invalid command \. 

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ir_act_client_pkey" 
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(103) already exists. 
CONTEXT:  COPY ir_act_client, line 21: "" 
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ir_act_report_xml_pkey" 
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(733) already exists. 
CONTEXT:  COPY ir_act_report_xml, line 59: "" 
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ir_act_server_pkey" 
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(703) already exists. 
CONTEXT:  COPY ir_act_server, line 6: "" 
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ir_act_window_pkey" 
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists. 
CONTEXT:  COPY ir_act_window, line 235: "334    Last Product Inventories        ir.actions.act_window   \N      1       2013-07-03 10:39:48.399509  2013-12-16 16:38:..." 
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ir_act_window_group_rel_act_id_gid_key" 
DETAIL:  Key (act_id, gid)=(76, 1) already exists. 
CONTEXT:  COPY ir_act_window_group_rel, line 14: "" 
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ir_act_window_view_pkey" 
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(100) already exists. 
CONTEXT:  COPY ir_act_window_view, line 88: ""
```

How to solve it ?

Comment: please try dumping with pg_dump -Fc and see what you get

Comment: @e4c5 thanks for advice ,I cant backup now because the database is loaded now , tonight I will try .

Comment: I try with -Fc and file is after backup 12GB, database is  20GB ,old file without -Fc was 30GB, now when I'm trying to restore this 12GB file have an errors `ERROR:  syntax error AT OR near "PGDMP"
LINE 1: PGDMPREVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM postgres;
        ^
GRANT
GRANT
GRANT
ERROR:  syntax error AT OR near ""
LINE 1:  "position" INTEGER,
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error AT OR near ""
LINE 1:     LANGUAGE c STRICT`

Comment: pg_dump 's out put is to be restored through pg_restore rather than psql

Comment: @e4c5 I try  `pg_restore -C -d postgres --disable-triggers /.../../...` and get some errors http://pastebin.com/r2TwSAPb But restore still continue now

Comment: @e4c5 I try pg-dumo without two problematic tables and backup work correctly after I manualy  import data of tables to the database without duplicate data and now it works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are exporting the data use [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html) with the -Fc option.

> Output a custom-format archive suitable for input into pg_restore.
>   Together with the directory output format, this is the most flexible
>   output format in that it allows manual selection and reordering of
>   archived items during restore. This format is also compressed by
>   default.

The compact format makes it easier to transfer between servers and depending on your IO load might even be faster to dump and restore as well.

If you intend to import the data into a database that already contains some tables complications are inevitable. You can overcome this situation by dumping with the --clean option.

Answer (score 1):

Below commands helped me to get rid of these errors:

pg_dump:
**RUN**

> pg_dump -O -d database_name > file_name.sql

- use -O option (in order to get rid of owner related errors.)

pg_restore:

- make sure before running the database restoring command, no tables are present in the database. (else this leads to a number of errors including violating key constraints etc.)
  **RUN**

> psql -1 database_name < file_name.sql

- using -1 option make sure, either the db is imported completely or nothing at all.
- also the execution stops at the first error, makes it easier to tackle one error at a time.